Kogito Completed Task move to Start Phase
In Kogito for completed task, I need to move the task again to start phase or to restart the task again. Is this can be done in Kogito Spring Boot?
I am trying completed task to move to start phase. But getting error when trying to do. Is this possible in Kogito Task.when trying call the completed task getting internal server error.
